# Table View Title Index

Tags: uitableview, indexing, alphabetical

I have my table view all set up and I can use the section index to jump to rows as I have them alphabetical but I want the table view to have titles like on the contact list of your device. For example:

```
A
Aeroplane

B
Bike
Bus

C
Car
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

NSInteger newRow = [self indexForFirstChar:title inArray:self.Make];
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRow inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using [`TLIndexPathDataModel`](http://tlindexpathtools.com/api/Classes/TLIndexPathDataModel.html) from [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com). You can use the block-based initializer to organize your items into sections based on the first letter of each make:

```
NSArray *makes = ...; // array of makes
TLIndexPathDataModel *dataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:makes sectionNameBlock:^NSString *(id item) {
    // assuming the items are NSStrings
    return [((NSString *)item) substringToIndex:1];
} identifierBlock:nil];
```

Then your indexing data source methods would look like:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.dataModel sectionNames];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [self.dataModel sectionForSectionName:title];
}
```

And your other data source and delegate methods can also be simplified by the data model APIs:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.dataModel.numberOfSections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataModel numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellId = ...;
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...; // dequeue cell
    NSString *make = [self.dataModel itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ... // configure cell
    return cell;
}
```

You can see a working example by running the ["Blocks" sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Blocks/Blocks/BlocksTableViewController.m) (although it is using some additional TLIndexPathTools components, `TLTableViewController` and `TLIndexPathController`, for simplicity).